# How to mask password stored in json file using bash script

Tags: json, bash, awk

I am using below script to mask sensitive data. which works fine for yml file.

```
awk '
   BEGIN {
       IGNORECASE = 1
   }
   $1 ~ /^('${3}')$/ {
      gsub( /[^-]/, "X", $2 )
   }
  { print }
' "${1}" > "${2}"
```

I pass source_file dest_file maskKeyword as command as below from my java class, but its not working.

```
 ./script.sh /abc/aa.json  /maskedaa.json   ‘"password":’
```

This is the my json file looks like.

```
[
  {
    "username": "abc",
    "password": “cdgiN1n/nSQE="
  },
  {
    "username": "abc",
    "password": "QXiFTkgKft6PhfkfjLtCWQE="
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

After you fix your JSON (incorrect curly quote on line 4, incorrect comma on line 9), you can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to do:

```
jq 'map(.password = "X")' aa.json
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this, how do we run this command , can i run this from inside a script or java code.

Comment: You run it like a regular command. You might need to install `jq` (check the tag link in my answer)

Comment: My implicit main point: use a proper JSON parser to parse JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that jq is preferable over awk in this case (more comments bellow). If you know that the json is pretty printed (only one entry per line) you could use a regex to break down the line in three pieces.

```
awk -v field="${3}" '
  BEGIN {
    IGNORECASE = 1
    regex = sprintf("^([^\"]*\"%s\"[^:]*:[^\"]*\")([^\"]*)(\".*)$", field)
  }

  $0 ~ regex {
    before   = gensub(regex, "\\1", 1)
    password = gensub(regex, "\\2", 1)
    after    = gensub(regex, "\\3", 1)
    masked   = gensub(/./, "X", "g", password)
    printf("%s%s%s\n", before, masked, after)
    next
  } { print }' "${1}" > "${2}"
```

The awk script I wrote is only matching the three components of a pretty printed line:

1. `[^\"]*\"%s\"[^:]*:[^\"]*\"` matches the entry line up to the semicolon. The field name must be between double quotes.
2. `[^\"]*`: matches the value of the entry
3. `\".*`: matches the ending double quote of the field and possibly comas and other fields.

Then the script mask the password replacing each character by a "X". Finally it prints the end result and skip the next block.

Caveats:

- The JSON must be pretty printed or have at least one password field per line
- The password field must be the first field of the line
- This script doesn't support escaped double quotes inside fields
- This script only works with gnu awk (or gawk)

*Comment: I would stick with the jq solution or maybe bake the jq into a bash file if portability is a must have.*

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment the previous answer, but is it possible to mask the password field keeping the password length using jq?

Comment: Yes.  E.g. use `gsub`.